# How to get the value of the slider bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-slider

How to get the values of the slider bootstrap to hidden iputs?

```html
<input type="hidden" name="min_value" id="min_value" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="max_value" id="max_value" value="">
```

```js
$(function () {
  $("#slider-range-s1").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    value: [0, 500]
  });
});
```

Comment: Try `$(selector).slider('getValue')`.

Answer (score 55):

I think it's currently broken.

Documentation states:

> Methods
>
> .slider('getValue')
>
> Get the value.

How ever, calling `$('#sliderDivId').slider('getValue')` returns the jQuery selector rather than the value...

For now you could manually grab it from the data object...
`$('#sliderDivId').data('slider').getValue()`

Comment: Your answer saved me and my pairing partner a lot of time and troubles!
Thank you!

Comment: Your answer was correct. It saved me lot of time. thanks

Comment: How do i get Min and Max values, please give explanation for that too.

Comment: It works but I seem to get 2 values in my output. Any ideas why?

Comment: @JoeD it is an array of the slider's value. The first index represent min value and second index is max value.

Comment: Min and max: $("#revenueHistogramInput").data("slider").getAttribute("min");
$("#revenueHistogramInput").data("slider").getAttribute("max");

Answer (score 6):

fast fix:

```
$.fn.slider = function (option, val) {

    if (typeof option == 'string') {
        if (this.length) {
            var data = this.eq(0).data('slider');
            if (data)
                return data[option](val);

            return null;
        }
    }

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('slider'),
            options = typeof option === 'object' && option;
        if (!data) {
            $this.data('slider', (data = new Slider(this, $.extend({}, $.fn.slider.defaults, options))));
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: props for fixing this plugin, may want to submit a pull request!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that there is more than 1 element with the same ID (the slider *div* and the *input* inside the slider *div*), in this example $('#sliderDivId'). If you select the input element with JQuery, you can use the slider API.

```
$('input[id="sliderDivId"]').slider('getValue')
```

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing it's a bit flaky but you can make it work:

1/ Make sure you specify an empty range starting "value[0]". Unless you do this its internal value field becomes undefined e.g.

```
$('#setBidDialogSlider').slider({ value: [0], max: max, step: 0.2, formater: function(v) { return v.toFixed(2)+"BTC" } });
```

2/ Now finally you can catch the value in the event

```
$('#setBidDialogSlider').slider().on('slide', function(ev) {
    $scope.dialog.order_value = ev.value*$scope.dialog.price;
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but ev.value returns undefined. =(

Comment: Thank you! `ev.value` works perfectly! Returns array for range slider.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but this is still broken but to fix it open up `bootstrap-sliders.js` and inject these three things:

the very end of the first function: `Slider`:

```
this.calculateValue();
```

---

right before:`return val;` in the `calculateValue` function

```
grandVal = val;
```

---

after the `$.fn.slider` function:

```
$.fn.sliderValue = function(){
    return grandVal;
};
var grandVal;
```

Now you can access the value by `$('#MySliderId').sliderValue()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this from the built in function

```
$( "#slider-range-s1" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    value: [ 0, 500 ]
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // u could use this function
        $(".min-slider-value").html( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $(".max-slider-value").html( "$" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        // or u could use this function
        $(".min-slider-value").html( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $(".max-slider-value").html( "$" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
    }
});
```

and thank you i thought i coud share this with you guys :D