# How to get multiple values from range slider - bootstrap-slider.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-slider.js - http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/  to give me range slider functionality. I have 9 sliders on one page and am getting the value only from the first slider.

How do I get the value for the other sliders?

```
<input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal" id="sl9" name="q12" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">


<input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal" id="sl2" name="q2" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">


<input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal" id="sl3" name="q3" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">

$(function(){
    $('#sl1').slider({
          formater: function(value) {
            return 'Current value: '+value;
          }
    });
    $('#sl2').slider({
          formater: function(value) {
            return 'Current value: '+value;
          }
    });
    $('#sl3').slider({
          formater: function(value) {
            return 'Current value: '+value;
          }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736694/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-slider-bootstrap

Comment: I have read the above mentioned possible duplicate question and I think that this is a different question, I CAN get the value of one of the sliders but not the others, so the bootstrap-slider.js is not broken.

Comment: Hi - not sure I understand, so I used the question linked to above to create the answer below :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the values like so:

```
console.log("Slider 1 = "+$("#sl1").data('slider').getValue());
console.log("Slider 2 = "+$("#sl2").data('slider').getValue());
console.log("Slider 3 = "+$("#sl3").data('slider').getValue());
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/D7Ctg/2/).

**Edit**

So to clarify - there does appear to be a problem that the slider is not actually updating the value of the underlying input. And when that input is posted via a form submit to the server, this causes a problem.

You could try adding an event to explicitly update the input when a slider changes, like so:

```
$(function(){
  $('#sl1').slider({
       formater: function(value) {
         return 'Current value: '+value;
       }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
  $('#sl2').slider({
        formater: function(value) {
          return 'Current value: '+value;
        }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
  $('#sl3').slider({
        formater: function(value) {
          return 'Current value: '+value;
        }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
});
```

and in each input set `value` to the same value as `data-slider-value` as this will be the default value i.e.

```
<input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal" id="sl2" name="q2" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">
```

Comment: Not sure how you figured that out, but it certainly works! Do you have a link to documentation related to your answer?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but get the same result, only get a value for the first slider.

Comment: @MichaelFreake, I just used the link above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736694/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-slider-bootstrap

Comment: @Grant - does the fiddle in the answer work for you? It works for me in Chrome and IE10. You may need to show more of your code or a link to a demo page if you are still having a problem.

Comment: @mccannf Sorry I might have not been clear enough, all the sliders do work and give me the correct values in the tooltip when I slide them around in FF, Chrome, IE the lot, but on $_POST I only get the first slider value. I do get the rest of the form $_POST values (non sliders).

Comment: Ok - that's clearer. I've edited the answer, hopefully this helps!

Comment: @mccannf I been trying to get this to work but no luck. No matter what I try I can only get the first slider to output a value on $_POST, if I remove the first slider nothing gets a $_POST output.

Comment: @Grant, yes - your HTML is wrong. You may not have closing tags in the right place. If you examine your HTML through a developer tool (not the source code, the actual DOM) the `</form>` tag appears after `<div class="span12 question">Group 2: </div>`...

Comment: I validated it a few times but a stray </div> crept in just after group 2. I removed it and it works great now. I really appreciate your help with this.