# how to use getValue for bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am using this http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/ for a slider in  a page I am working on,I don't understand the api. Can someone help me with this ?

```
$(..).slider('getValue')
```

returns the dom element while I saw this in the code

```
$(..).slider().getValue()
```

which returns a method not found error. I am aware of the .slide event which can be used for this,but how do you access the value directly ?

Comment: The first option looks fine. Can you show your markup please?

Comment: Are all the libraries included?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value of the slider bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736694/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-slider-bootstrap)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'am using it this way

```
<input type="text" id="slider1" class="span2 slider" value="80" data-slider-min="50" data-slider-max="90" data-slider-step="0.1" data-slider-value="83"  data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
 $('.slider').on('slide', function (ev) {
        console.log($('#slider1').val());


    });
```

So I access value with `$('#slider1').val()`. I hope this is going to be helpful

Comment: Yes, it works! The value of $(selector).slider('getValue') seems to be meaningless, but I don't know why. Thanks!

Comment: not that .val() will return "" if the slider wasn't moved

Comment: @ılǝ because of that you initialize value to some number like i did value="80"

Comment: Thank you so much @DejanG I've been trying to fix this problem for a while!

Comment: From what I've seen $(selector).slider('getValue')  will return an array for a range, while $(selector).val() will return a string.

Answer (score 3):

**The slider is technically a text input field.**

So you can simply use 
`$("#inputFieldID").val()`

This will not provide any value until the slider is moved. So specify the initial value using the ***value*** attribute of the input tag.

Comment: This works great, just important to remember to provide a different id to the slider, eg data-slider-id="something-else", and access the original input field and not the slider id ($("#slider-id").val() always return empty string).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this from the built in function

```
$("#rating").slider({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        userRating = ui.value;
        // this will give you the real value of the slider after the change.
        alert(userRating); 
    }
});
```

and thank you i thought i coud share this with you guys :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#idSlider').data('slider').getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in bootstrap5:

```
<input type="range" id="slider1" class="form-range" min="1" max="10" step="0.5" value="7" />

<span id="slider1_val"></span>

$("#slider1").on("change", function() {
    $("#slider1_val").text($('#slider1').val());
});
```