# bootstrap slider always returns "10"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have the following slider:

```
<input id="sliderInput" class="slider slider-horizontal form-control" type="text" value=""
   data-slider-min="5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1"
   data-slider-value="10" data-slider-orientation="horizontal">
```

And combined the following javascript:

```
$('#sliderInput').slider()
$('#tester').click(function()
{
    alert($('#sliderInput').data.getValue());
})
```

However no matter what i do the value returned is always 10.

I read the following question:

[How to get value of bootstrap-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736694/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-slider-bootstrap)

However this didn't do anything for me :S

It seems it might be broken but can anyone tell me if it is possible to get the correct value? (maybe a hack?)

Comment: What did you expect to get?

Comment: `$('#sliderInput').val()`?

Comment: @Huangism i want to get the value that the slider is on

Comment: @njzk2 $('#sliderInput').val() returns ""

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle or something to illustrate this? I can quite figure out which combination of libraries/versions you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC that method is broken.

Try:

`$('#sliderInput').data('slider').getValue()`

Comment: Still prints out 10 :S