# How to get the value of a Bootstrap toggle button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I have this markup and jQuery but I cannot successfully capture the button value or on/off or any form of recognition of the setting of the toggle:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="payMethod">Payment Method</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline bootstrap-switch-noPad" for="payMethod">
          <input type="checkbox" id="payMethod" name="payMethod" data-size="small" value="Credit" data-on-text="Credit" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="Cash" data-off-color="warning" tabindex="13">
        </label>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#payMethod').on( 'change', function() {
  alert('slid');
}); // does not work

$( "#payMethod" ).click(function() {
  alert( $('#payMethod').val() );
}); // does not work

$('#payMethod').change(function() {
  alert('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
}); // does not work

$('input[type=checkbox][name=payMethod]').change(function() {
  alert('help'); // does not work
});
```

Here are the slider buttons (there is no checkbox):
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 34):

you can try this

```
$("#payMethod").change(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
       //run code
    }else{
       //run code
    }
});
```

Comment: Right, but the Bootstrap plugin shows a slider button and there is no checkbox. That's why I am having the trouble I guess

Comment: did you already checked this link? I hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736694/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-slider-bootstrap

Comment: the slider('get value') does not work either. I just can't get anything to cause it to fire on click or change or slide, etc.

Comment: $(':checkbox').checkboxpicker().change(function() {
  ...
});

Answer (score 15):

You can use simple like this:
If in your html code you using id=abc for bootstrap toggle.

```
$('#abc').prop('checked')
```

Output is: true or false. (True when toggle in on, and false when toggle is off)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the script placed before the HTML tag? If so, then move the script after the Html tag, or place the script inside jQuery function as below:

```
$(function()
{

    $('#payMethod').on( 'change', function() {
         alert('slid');
    }); // does not work

    $( "#payMethod" ).click(function() {
         alert( $('#payMethod').val() );
    }); // does not work

    $('#payMethod').change(function() {
        alert('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
    }); // does not work

    $('input[type=checkbox][name=payMethod]').change(function() {
        alert('help'); // does not work
    });
});
```

The best practice is to use the later one, which place the script inside the jQuery function. Because the scripts will be rendered after all HTML tags has been rendered.

Comment: it's a snippet of the code. The entire script is right before the `</body>` tag, after the jQuery Lib loads.

Comment: I have made the most progress with your suggestions here @OetawanAryaChandra. I don't have it working exactly yet, but tanks for your guidance.

Comment: `$( "#payMethod" ).click(function() {
     alert( $('#payMethod').val() );
});` this one is firing but only on **Credit**, **Cash** does not return

Comment: `<script>
// reveal credit card block
$(function() {
$( "#payMethod" ).click(function() {
  if( $('#payMethod').val() == 'Credit' ) {
    $('#payMethod').val( 'Cash' );
    $('.creditCardInfo').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#payMethod').val( 'Credit' );
    $('.creditCardInfo').show();
  }
});
});
</script>` this comes close but the toggling happens every other click. In other words, my block hides on click #2 then shows on click #4 then hides on click #6 and shows again on click #8. I need it to toggle every other click

Answer (score 1):

Your script should need to be inside html body.

```
<Body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="payMethod">Payment Method</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="checkbox-inline bootstrap-switch-noPad" for="payMethod">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="payMethod" name="payMethod" data-size="small" value="Credit" data-on-text="Credit" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="Cash" data-off-color="warning" tabindex="13">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        $('#payMethod').on( 'change', function() {
            alert('slid');
        });
    </script>
</Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome DevTool `Ctrl+Shift+i`->`Element`. I right clicked on my toggle button and select `inspect`. Then, I toggled the button to on and off. Then, only I realized, the fired event is not on the input element but a div added by [BootstrapToggle](https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/).

[image]

Hence, with that in my code, I added listener to the aforementioned div and read the state of my toggle button then. My codes:

```js
$('div[data-toggle="toggle"]').click(function() {
      console.log( "toggle_show_cancelled value: " + $("#toggle_show_cancelled").prop("checked"))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '#payMethod', function (e) {
if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
  console.log("Checkbox is checked.");
}else{
  console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
}
```

Try this one: