# Slider in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am creating an app with cordova. I am getting an error with slider.
**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="slider">
    <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/temperature.js"></script>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function () {
    var handle = $("#custom-handle");
    $("#slider").slider({
        create: function () {
            handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            handle.text(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

**ERROR**

> VM93 jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance
>       at Function.error (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:1821)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3:10693)
>       at Function.each (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:2882)
>       at n.fn.init.each (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:847)
>       at n.fn.init.a.fn.(anonymous function) [as slider] (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3:10498)
>       at HTMLDivElement.create (http://localhost:4400/scripts/temperature.js:5:33)
>       at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._trigger (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3:14553)
>       at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWidget (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3:11664)
>       at new a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3:9187)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js:3:10922)

Comment: you referenced in the `head` three different libraries with sliders, i believe you need to clean-up, first.

Answer (score 1):

On the line:

```
handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
```

Should be

```
handle.text($(this).slider.val());
```

or

```
handle.text($(this).slider.attr("value");
```

Edit: Actually found a thread on a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736694/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-slider-bootstrap). With your code, you are trying to access a method called "value" on the slider, however, this method does not exist. 
According to the documentation on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-slider), this can be accessed through the 'getValue' method. Therefore, your code should be updated to:

```
handle.text($(this).slider("getValue"));
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.